# Change log4j properties at runtime

Tags: log4j

I need to change my log4j properties (rootLogger, MaxFileSize, etc.) at runtime.
How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-change-my-log4j-settings-while-my-web-application-is-running.html

Comment: In log4j 2.x `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator` can be helpful in some cases https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#reconfig_level_from_code

Answer (score 10):

Use `LogManager.resetConfiguration();` to clear the current config and configure it again.

Another approach is to build a new appender and replace the old one with it (most appenders don't support changing their config). This way, all the loggers (and their levels, etc) stay intact.

For this to work, I usually add the first appender from code (and not with a config file). That allows me to save a reference which makes it more simple to remove it later.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you explain better? I have five Logger's using the configuration of log4j... I need to change the MaxFileSize (i.e.), and set this new prop for all my Loggers (at runtime)...

Comment: A logger is just a key. It doesn't have a MaxFileSize. The file size is a property of an *appender*. Appenders can be attached to loggers and they will do something with log messages. So what you need to do: Find the **appenders** (loggers have methods to get all attached loggers) and then you must replace them.

Comment: Ok Aaron. I've try to do with this code: Logger l = Logger.getLogger(myclass); LogManager.resetConfiguration(); l.setLevel(Level.DEBUG); RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(); appender.setMaxBackupIndex(numberOfLogsToKeep); logger.addAppender(appender); It doesn't works. How can I change the appender of my logger?

Comment: I got it! thanks for helping! i just iterate above the getAllAppenders and set the props in each appender...

Comment: @AaronDigulla which log4j version has this API?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I will if it works for latest version log4j 2.11

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-tdb/log4j.properties
has a log4j properties file.

Based on it I am using the configureLog4j helper function shown below like this:

**set jena logging level at runtime**

```java
String level=org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF.toString();
if (debug)
  level=org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO.toString();
configureLog4j(level);
```

**configureLog4J function**

```java
  /**
   * configure Log4J
   * @param level -the level to use e.g. "INFO", "DEBUG", "OFF" 
   * see org.apache.log4j.Level
   */
  private void configureLog4j(String level) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("log4j.rootLogger", level+", stdlog");
    props.put("log4j.appender.stdlog", "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
    props.put("log4j.appender.stdlog.target", "System.out");
    props.put("log4j.appender.stdlog.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
    props.put("log4j.appender.stdlog.layout.ConversionPattern",
        "%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %-25c{1} :: %m%n");
    // Execution logging
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.arq.info", level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.arq.exec", level);
    // TDB loader
    props.put("log4j.logger.org.apache.jena.tdb.loader", level);
    // Everything else in Jena
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena", level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.org.apache.jena.riot", level);
    // TDB
    // TDB syslog.
    props.put("log4j.logger.TDB", level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb", level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.transaction", level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.transaction.NodeTableTrans",
        level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.transaction.TransactionManager",level);
    props.put("log4j.logger.com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.transaction.TestTransSystem",level);
    // Joseki server
    props.put("log4j.logger.org.joseki", level);
    LogManager.resetConfiguration();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
  }
```