# Over- rewrite .properties

Tags: java, apache, logging, netbeans, log4j

i want to overwrite my log4j.properties file so that the user can configure it at will.
is it possible to do that?

e.g.

```
log4j.appender.toFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

the user wants the MBI to be 15 so i need something to rewrite it to

```
log4j.appender.toFile.MaxBackupIndex=15
```

is it possible?

thank you for your help

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Can't you just make a backup copy of the config file and then change that value?

Answer (score 0):

Simple create CRUD objects with File load/store operations and some kind of GUI interface (It can be simple html page if it is WEB-app). To reload properties you can check: http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/238
or [Change log4j properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592399/change-log4j-properties-at-runtime).

Comment: i didnt understand what CRUD is but i'll work it up, thank you ^^

Comment: Create Read Update Delete - just type of app from the functional approach