# Tomcat memory leak issue on log4j thread

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, log4j

I'm facing issue of memory leak in log4j v1.How to resolve this memory leak issue.
This method is periodically check log4j.properties file update in my class.

> PropertyConfigutaror.configureAndWatch(time_ms);

But during shutdown tomcat memory leak issue comes. Logs are below:

> 06-Oct-2016 15:13:55.973 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [myapp] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Thread-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>
> java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) 
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:103)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it solved your issue.Please inform how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is there a way to get log4j to automatically reload a configuration file if it changes?**
>
> Yes. Both the DOMConfigurator and the PropertyConfigurator support automatic reloading through the configureAndWatch method. See the API documentation for more details.
>
> **Because the configureAndWatch launches a separate wathdog thread, and because there is no way to stop this thread in log4j 1.2, the configureAndWatch method is unsafe for use in J2EE envrironments where applications are recycled.** [(1)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6)

The second statement is also true for a not full-blown app server like Tomcat.

I would suggest to update to log4j 2 if you want to reload your configuration during runtime.

What's also possible is to write your own properties file reader and set the log configuration programmatically. For more information see [Change Log4j properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592399/change-log4j-properties-at-runtime).